# Cant install typescript@4.9 on angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, npm-install

I really want to use the satisfies operator and when I try to install typescript@4.9, I get the following error.

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: back-office@0.0.0
npm WARN Found: typescript@4.8.4
npm WARN node_modules/typescript
npm WARN   peer typescript@"~4.8.2" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm WARN     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.0.1" from the root project
npm WARN   3 more (@ngtools/webpack, @angular/compiler-cli, the root project)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer typescript@"~4.8.2" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm WARN   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.0.1" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: back-office@0.0.0
npm WARN Found: typescript@4.8.4
npm WARN node_modules/typescript
npm WARN   peer typescript@"~4.8.2" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm WARN     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.0.1" from the root project
npm WARN   3 more (@ngtools/webpack, @angular/compiler-cli, the root project)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer typescript@">=4.8.2 <4.9" from @angular/compiler-cli@15.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm WARN   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm WARN   2 more (@ngtools/webpack, the root project)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: back-office@0.0.0
npm WARN Found: typescript@4.8.4
npm WARN node_modules/typescript
npm WARN   peer typescript@"~4.8.2" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm WARN     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^15.0.1" from the root project
npm WARN   3 more (@ngtools/webpack, @angular/compiler-cli, the root project)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer typescript@">=4.8.2 <4.9" from @angular/compiler-cli@15.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm WARN   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm WARN   2 more (@ngtools/webpack, the root project)
```

Doesn't angular support 4.9, or is it a local problem. And if it does not support it, where can I ask when will it be supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is not supported yet. but will be supported soon.
you can watch this PR for updates:
https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/48005

Answer (score 1):

TS 4.9 support has landed with the [release of Angular 15.1](https://github.com/angular/angular/releases/tag/15.1.0) !